# Conditional joining of dataframes

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

I have persons with multiple care continuums. For each care continuum, I need to calculate the total received treatment hours. The total received treatment hours must include all treatment hours from the start of continuum up to one year (365 days).

**Persons' dataframe**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

persons = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ziygvwnbvq73fc/persons.csv?dl=1") %>% 
  mutate(continuum_start = ymd(continuum_start)) %>% 
  select(-1)
  
persons
```

[image]

**Treatments' dataframe**

```
treatments = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nfokiheo43lwjy/treatments.csv?dl=1") %>% 
  mutate(treatment_date = ymd(treatment_date)) %>% 
  select(-1)

treatments
```

[image]

**Desired result should like like this**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need total hours per ID for those who were followed for more than a year (>365 days)

If so, you need:

- merge the `persons` and `treatments` datasets;
- check the difference in days;
- filter results whose difference is greater than 365 days;
- group by `id`;
- add up the hours of care received

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

persons %>% 
  left_join(treatments) %>% 
  mutate(time = treatment_date - continuum_start) %>% 
  filter(time > 365) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(received_hours_one_year = sum(received_hours))


# A tibble: 162 × 2
   id     received_hours_one_year
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 ID1036                     0.5
 2 ID111                      4  
 3 ID1111                     2  
 4 ID1116                     6  
 5 ID116                      3.5
 6 ID1209                     0.5
 7 ID1210                     1  
 8 ID1213                     0.5
 9 ID1243                     3  
10 ID125                     34.5
```